# Return the list of colored cells based on certain conditions

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this in `Sheet1`:

[image]

and in `Sheet2` I want to lookup and filter the colored data, and the result would be:

[image]

**Goal: to return the list of colored cells**

*Filtering (lookup) conditions:*

**1. Return the colored cell (copy/paste the exact cell content) from columns** ***J*** **to** ***V*** **from `Sheet1` into same cell references in `Sheet2` . (the color could be filled in by any color)**

**2.For each colored cell in the specified range, return as well the cells from columns** ***E***, ***H*** **, and** ***I***.

**3. Ignore the cells (whether colored or not), whose content is equal to** ***NA*** *(asterisk NA asterisk).*

*The number of rows is 10000+ but the number of the colored cells will not exceed some 500.*

*VBA code is preferred, but if it can be done also with formulas, it is also acceptable.*

[Here is the example sheet for the ease of copy pasting.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73smSNUQ01-X2NpeEUtUDRmNEU/view?usp=sharing)

### Update

The cells are colored by conditional formatting rules in `Sheet1`. Actually Grominet's [answer is working only for cells manually colored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30556776/4835480). How to take into account the conditional formatting colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to loop every lines, and test every columns to your criteria (not NA and colored). If true, copy the colored cell. And add the header line.

Here a start code working, need to be adapt to exactly reach your goal.

```
Sub test()

Dim aLine As Long
Dim aColumn As Long
Dim lastLineS2 As Long 'lastLine of sheet2
Dim test As Boolean

lastLineS2 = 3

For aLine = 3 To 100
   test = False
   For aColumn = 1 To 50
      If aColumn > 9 And aColumn < 22 Then
          If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aLine, aColumn).Value <> "*NA*" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aLine, aColumn).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then
              Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastLineS2, aColumn) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aLine, aColumn)
              test = True
          End If
      End If
   Next aColumn
   If test Then 'copy line heading
      For aColumn = 1 To 9
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastLineS2, aColumn) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aLine, aColumn)
      Next aColumn
      lastLineS2 = lastLineS2 + 1
   End If
Next aLine

End Sub
```

Comment: it is not working! could you please check if it runs at your end?

Comment: it's work on my side, could you explain what is done, or not, or message error?

Comment: Sorry, yeah you are right, it works, but I forgot to explain that my cells are colored by the conditional formatting. THat is why it is not working. But when they are manually colored, yes it works. How to modify it to take into account the conditional formatting color?

Comment: Why not integrate the conditional test to the VBA code instead of using color detection?

Comment: how to do it? could you please edit your answer and integrate this condition? thanks. i am vba newbie and completely zero beginner.

Comment: depend of your condition... Here it take only not "*NA*" and colored cell. You can add any condition by adding like this: Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(aLine, aColumn).Value = 1234

Comment: actually my cells are colored by certain conditional formatting rules in the original sheet. The cells are not manually colored. Your code only works for cells if they are colored manually, not for cells that are automatically colored by Conditional Formatting. How to add `FormatConditions` statement to your set of conditions?

Comment: You can't check if a format conditions is true or not for a dedicated cell. The format condition is applied to many cells or range, not just one. You should directly put your conditional formula in VBA. If you don't know how do it. I suggest you start with [tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html) on basics VBA programming on the web.

Comment: I have more than 1000+rows and more than 30 conditional formatting rules, which take into account more than 100 columns. Is it possible to convert the conditional formatting colors to normal colors in another sheet first and then use your code?

Comment: @grominet - You can resolve the CF rule's formula *as it pertains to the top-left cell in the range* or resolve it as an R1C1 formula since the latter will be the same for every cell. See [ConvertFormula where the formula does not vary relative to cell but should](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/convertformula-where-the-formula-does-not-vary/8beb957a-eef3-4102-b2e9-8f07905ca339?msgid=6f09b6b2-0e21-4b30-9a6e-0a958b32f0d7)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub ttt()
Dim cl As Range, n&
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each cl In .UsedRange
        If cl.Row > 2 And cl.Column <> 5 And _
           cl.Column <> 8 And cl.Column <> 9 And _
           cl.Interior.Pattern = xlNone And _
           cl.Value <> "*NA*" And cl.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
           cl.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cl
    n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    While n <> 2
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("J" & n & ":V" & n)) = 0 Then
            .Rows(n).Delete
        End If
        n = n - 1
    Wend
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately, the code is yielding nothing. help please

Comment: code has been updating with conditional formating verification, try again